# Why does the borrowing method for subtracting stop working if the bottom number is bigger?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

My brother was given the problem $2.3-4$, and tried to solve it using the standard one over the other format. $.3-.0=.3, 2-4=-2$, answer is $-2.3$. He looks at the answer in the back and sees that it should be $-1.7$. Not being the strongest at math, and having missed that day's lecture, he asks me why his answer ( and method )  is wrong. Unfortunately, it has been almost 11 years since I've sat in an algebra class, and I was never too strong at theory anyway. Sure I can show him how to get the right answer, but now I've got this nagging question in my head why that method doesn't work.

Why does vertically written subtraction problems only yield the right answer if the bottom number is smaller?

```
  2.3
 -4.0≠-2.3
```

Comment: The method yields the perfectly correct result $-2+0.3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually works!

Notice that $0.3 - 0.0 = \color\red{+} 0.3$

$2.0 - 4.0 = \color\red{-}2$

Add those two results, answer = $-2 + 0.3 = -1.7$, which is the correct answer.

Edit: In normal setting (where upper number is bigger), we don't have to worry about taking care of signs because all results are positive (the possibly negative ones are taken care of by borrowing from next place), and addition of positive numbers is always positive.

However, one can perfectly calculate partial negative and partial positive results and add them with correct signs to get the correct answer.

Comment: Ah! I've never thought about that step of combining the partial answers. I did a quick test to see if this method works with borrowing, and it does. 2.3 - 4.6 => +0.7 - 3.0 => -2.3.